# My cat won’t eat but he’ll drink water

Tags: cats

My male cat is 11 and lately he’s not wanting to eat much he’ll drink water he even spits out he’s cat treats what should I do please help Thank you

Comment: Changes in eating or drinking behaviour might be a sign of illness so you need to take your cat to the vet,if your cat stop eating for more than 24 hours it is an emergency that need imediate veterinary care.please take a look at the answers here https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2529/what-should-i-do-if-my-cat-stops-eating-and-starts-hiding-more

Answer (score 5):

Cats might not want to eat for hundreds of reasons, but the most common causes in combination with polydipsia (increased drinking) would include kidney failure and diabetic crisis.

To diagnose these conditions would require blood and urine tests. Additional diagnostics such as x-rays or ultrasound may also be advised depending on the case.

Inappetence can quickly get serious. Inappetence is usually quickly followed by dehydration, as pets who are very thirsty often cannot keep up with the fluids they need, even if we see them drinking a lot. With mild illness, they might recover in a day or so, but if inappetence persists longer than this then veterinary attention is needed. Addressing the underlying cause is key, but medications can be given to stimulate appetite and prevent nausea, and fluids given to maintain hydration.

Unfortunately these are not the sort of things that can be diagnosed or treated over the internet. Your cat needs to see a vet as soon as possible.